# How to make parent container fit child border-radius

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a container wrapping a bunch of div. The child divs' borders changes when focused,  resulting in the corners of the parent container being visible when the child divs' corners are rounded. (As shown below)

[image: Extra space]

My question is: Instead of changing the entire border radius of the parent container, is it possible to have the parent container's border fit its adjacent child elements' border? Would be nice if pure css can achieve this, but Javascript can be used if not possible.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.card {
  flex: 30%;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 30vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid gray;
  background-color: black;
}

.card:focus {
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="card" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="card" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="card" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it's definitely possible in an inelegant and brutish way. First, on click, determine if the selected element is in a corner. There's probably a more clever way to do this, but at the very least you can compare x,y coordinates vs parent, and determine if the element butt's into a corner. Second, when you know if a corner is affected, then you simply apply specific `border-radius` to the parent, e.g. `border-top-left-radius: 15px`. If doing this, I'd keep a global radius value and reference it: `--myRadius: brown;` and use it like: `border-top-left-radius: var(--myRadius)`.

Comment: Sorry, correction in above comment: `--myRadius: 15px;`.

Comment: Another solution is to have the design look better. If you don't have space between a child's border and the parent's side, your layout will look cramped. Add a `10px` padding to your parent, and you won't have this issue anymore. The layout will be able to breathe, and you don't have to worry about fixing the parent's `border-radius`.

Comment: @Kalnode Determining if the element butt's into a corner by loop through all the cards would work! Definitely brutish though!

Comment: @rickard-elimää I agree, might just do that if there is no easy CSS or JS! (The reason there was no padding is because this container is nested into other containers, so adding padding to each layer will make it looks a bit too much padding.)

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with JavaScript as with pure css it would be a bit challenging. Here's how I would do it:

```js
const wrapper = document.querySelector(".wrapper");
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

cards.forEach((card) => {
  card.addEventListener("focus", () => {
    wrapper.style.borderRadius = "15px";
  });

  card.addEventListener("blur", () => {
    const focusedCards = Array.from(cards).filter((c) => c === document.activeElement);
    if (focusedCards.length === 0) {
      wrapper.style.borderRadius = "0";
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: black;
}

.card {
  flex: 30%;
  max-width: 50%;
  height: 30vh;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: solid gray;
  background-color: black;
}

.card:focus {
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: solid white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="card" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="card" tabindex="0"></div>
  <div class="card" tabindex="0"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you do about parent corners not covered by a card? They should never be rounded.

Comment: @Kalnode that is indeed tricky one, I don't think it is part of the question, or is it?

Comment: Yes, it is "...have the parent container's border fit its adjacent child elements' border" but also implied because the default state of everything (unfocused) is a square corner.

Comment: Yes other corners without adjacent child should be squared!